# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to save value of jsp into database butt it giving me error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException
```

Kindly help me out

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Would you share your code ?

Comment: If you use osgi depedencies, add as embedded depedency the jnlp-api and import (the) package com.sun.jnlp.*.